# Additive form of a spectral decomposition?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am in a class on the mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics. My professor has been talking about spectral decompositions, but they are of a different form than the ones I am used to. I have mostly used the form $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ where $S$ is a matrix of eigenvectors, and $\Lambda$ is a matrix of eigenvalues.

However, he has phrased the entire discussion using an "additive form" $A=\displaystyle \sum_{Ax=\lambda x} \lambda P_\lambda$ where the $P_\lambda$ are projection matrices. I was wondering if these really represent the same concept, and if so, if there is a convenient translation between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two are the same, let $E_1, \cdots, E_n$ be the eigensubspaces and $P_i$ be the projection onto $E_i$. Let $x$ be a vector, then $Ax = A(x_1+ \cdots x_n)$ for some $x_i \in E_i$. Hence $Ax = Ax_1 + \cdots +Ax_n = \sum \lambda_i x_i= \sum \lambda_i P_i (x)$.

On the other hand, if you choose a unitary basis $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ such that $v_i \in E_i$, then the matrix $S$ with column vector $v_i$ would satisties $A = S\Lambda S^*$.

It is more convenient to use projections as one needs to deal with infinite dimensional spaces and one cannot use matrices to describe linear map on this space. In QM, for example, the state space is infinite dimensional and the Schrodinger operator is a operator on the state space.