# Additive decomposition of positive definite Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that one has a positive definite hermitian matrix $Q$ and wants to write it as a finite sum of positive definite hermitian matrices, like $Q=\sum_{i=1}^NQ_i$. Is there a "natural" way of (possibly uniquely) decomposing such a matrix in a non-trivial way? By "natural" I mean in the sense that every positive integer can be uniquely decomposed as a product of prime numbers. By trivial I mean decompositions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^Nc_iQ_i$, where $\sum_{i=1}^Nc_i=1$.

There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523860/additive-form-of-a-spectral-decomposition) answered in this forum, but I am not sure if it answers my question. Could the rank-1 decomposition of $Q$ with the help of its SVD considered such an answer?

Thanks a lot in advance, and I am sorry if the question is too general or vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H\in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ be a positive semidefinite Hermitian
matrix. Let $r$ be its rank. Then $H$ has $r$ real, positive eigenvalues, while the
eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ has multiplicity $n − r$. There exist $p$ column vectors $X_{\alpha}$ ,
pairwise orthogonal, such that

$H = X_1 (X_1)^* +\dots+ X_r (X_r)^*$

Finally, $H$ is positive definite if and only if $r = n$ (in which case, $0$ is
not an eigenvalue).

Since $H$ is positive Hermitian so $H=UDU^*$ for some unitary $U$,
and $D=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r,0,0,\dots,0)$

and define $X_{\alpha}=\sqrt{\lambda_{\alpha}} U_{\alpha}$, $U_{\alpha}$ are collumns of $U$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How are the vectors $X_a$ related to the eigenvectors of $H$?

Comment: carefully look how we defined $X_{\alpha}$

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the answer I was looking for!